# Editing Lua file

Tags: lua, edit

I play Sims Freeplay ans I try to find files ton edit my money ingame. I find a filé named : Cheats.lua ans this is the code inside :

```
cheatModule = SFP.Get().cheatModule
playerModule = SFP.Get().playerModule
            
function AddXP(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Adding XP: ' .. amount)
    cheatModule:AddXP(amount)
end

function AddSimoleons(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Adding Simoleons: ' .. amount)
    cheatModule:AddSimoleons(amount)
end

function AddLifestylePoints(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Adding Lifestyle Points: ' .. amount)
    cheatModule:AddLifestylePoints(amount)
end

function AddCurrency3(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Adding Currency3: ' .. amount)
    cheatModule:AddCurrency3(amount)
end

function SetXP(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting XP to: ' .. amount)
    playerModule.xp = amount
end
      
function SetSimoleons(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Simoleons to: ' .. amount)
    playerModule.simoleons = amount
end

function SetLifestylePoints(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Lifestyle Points to: ' .. amount)
    playerModule.lifestylePoints = amount
end

function SetCurrency3(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Currency3 to: ' .. amount)
    playerModule.currency3 = amount
end  

function SkipFTUE()
    cheatModule:SkipFTUE()
end

function SpawnSim()
    cheatModule:SpawnSim()
end

function KillSim()
    cheatModule:KillSim()
end

function SetUberSim(isUberSim)
    cheatModule:SetUberSim(isUberSim)
end

function GiveAmbitionProgress()
    cheatModule:GiveAmbitionProgress()
end

function RemoveAmbitionProgress()
    cheatModule:RemoveAmbitionProgress()
end

function DoAutonomy()
    cheatModule:DoAutonomy()
end

function SetSimAgeInfant()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeInfant()
end

function SetSimAgeToddler()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeToddler()
end

function SetSimAgeTween()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeTween()
end

function SetSimAgeTeenager()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeTeenager()
end

function SetSimAgeAdult()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeAdult()
end

function SetSimAgeSenior()
    cheatModule:SetSimAgeSenior()
end

function SkipFTUE()
    -- cheatModule:SkipFTUE()
    -- TODO: There is an issue calling skipFTUE
end
```

How can I edit this to change money ?

I have already try to edit this line like this :

```
function SetSimoleons(10000)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Simoleons to: ' 10000 amount)
    playerModule.simoleons = 10000
end
```

But when I execute it with the compiler I have this error :

/usr/local/lua-5.3.5/luac53: script.lua:34: or '...' expected near '10000'

I need help please,

Alden Vacker

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure how you got from

```
function SetSimoleons(amount)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Simoleons to: ' .. amount)
    playerModule.simoleons = amount
end
```

to

```
function SetSimoleons(10000)
    amount = amount or 10000
    im.log.info('Setting Simoleons to: ' 10000 amount)
    playerModule.simoleons = 10000
end
```

why do you replace `..` with `10000`? That doesn't make any sense even for a beginner.

`..` is the concatenation operator. It is used to append the value of variable `amount` to the string `'Setting Simoleons to:` .

Also you replaced the function parameter name `amount` with `10000` which also doesn't make sense.

`10000` is the default amount of Simoleons if you don't provide an argument to `SetSimoleons` as in `SetSimoleons()`.

This file strongly suggests that you somehow need to call those functions. Not to alter them. I mean you did not even change the number values. You just messed up the code.

I strongly suggest that you learn some basic Lua befor you continue. Replacing random stuff with other random stuff doesn't yield any good.

Comment: Didn't you have any idea yo how this can work ? I don't really have time to learn Lua...

Comment: you have time to play Sims but not to learn Lua? you can learn what you need in a few hours. but as I said unless you know how to execute those functions there is no point in changing them.

Comment: No, I don't play Sims I am just tweaking games files. If another people kwnow how to make it work, please answer me. Thanks for your answers, Piglet